# Avoid intersection is missing QGIS 2.10, 2.8.2

Tags: qgis, intersection

I need to digitize a lot of polygons and I want to ease my work with the 'avoid intersection' button so that the new polygons do not overlap. In the manual I found (for version 2.6) that the button is hidden in 'snap options', but I can't find it.

How do I activate 'avoid intersection'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Snapping options` dialog, change the `Snapping mode` option to "Advanced".  My Osgeo4W version of QGIS has a slight bug where if "Advanced" is already selected, you must change it to any other option and then switch it back.

Comment: That's it, thanks! Furthermore my window was too small so I couldn't see the box to turn the 'avoid intersection' on, I had to scroll to the right. Finally I found it =)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just need to turn Snapping mode to Advanced with the dropdown box.